# Why doesn't == operation work in server in PHP but works in localhost?

Tags: php, if-statement, equals-operator

I tried this code to localhost and it worked fine but when I upload it in the server it doesn't work and it has the problem with this line:`if($key[$j]==  $this->test);`. Can you help ? :)

```
<?php
    class key {
        public $test;
        public $result;
        public $imp;
        public $sentc;

        function __construct() {
            $this->test = $_GET['c'];
            $arr = explode("-", $this->test);
            $p = PRODUCTS::getallteedrow();
            $tproduct = PRODUCTS::getAlltaeed();
            $ii = 0;

            for ($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
                $pp = $tproduct[$i];
                $key = $pp['keyword'];
                $key = explode(',', $key);
                $count = count($key);

                for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
                    if ($key[$j] == $this->test) {
                        $this->result[$ii] = PRODUCTS::products_SelectRow($pp['id']);
                        $this->sentc = $this->result[$ii]['description'];
                        $this->sentc = explode(" ", $this->sentc);

                        if (count($this->sentc) >= 30) {
                            $this->sentc = array_slice($this->sentc, 0, 30);
                            $this->sentc = implode(" ", $this->sentc);
                            $this->result[$ii]['description'] = $this->sentc . ".....";
                        }

                        echo $this->result[$ii]['description'];
                        $ii++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

It is PHP code and I work in PHP MVC.

Comment: turn on error reporting and let us know what the error says

Comment: how i can turn it on ??

Comment: google 'show php errors' and then copy and paste that code at the top of your script

Comment: try changing it to '==='

Comment: Could it be that you have an issue with case sensitivity?

Comment: i tried '==='but it dosent work again :(